# Row level security with Presto and Apache Ranger

Tags: apache-ranger, trino

I'm running Presto (348) with a several catalogs configured. In Apache Ranger (2.1.0) I have enabled the Presto plugin, which is working fine for general access.

In the Jira Ticker [RANGER-2754](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RANGER-2754), it's described that row level filtering and column masking is enabled.

Somehow the WebUi is not showing up the option for these kinds of policies.

[image]

I'm expecting somehow a Tab within the UI like in the Hive Plugin
[image]

Comment: I do not know the answer. Please note however that Presto (the one that you're using) is Trino now (https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html) and so the Ranger integration will need to be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, fortunately. Did you reuse the database of the old version's ranger? If so, you need to create a new database for ranger-admin-2.1. Then you can see the tab within the UI like in the Hive Plugin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).